# Waiting for handle request synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So this problem has been bugging me for quite a while. Basically I have coinflip game system setup where a user creates a lobby for other users to join and when one joins, they flip a coin and the winner gets both users' points.

The lobby creator can cancel the lobby if no one joins for a while and gets his points back. This is where the problem rises. If the creator requests to cancel the lobby 2 or more times with very little time between the requests, before the first request is fully complete and the database is updated, any other cancel request also get executed since the status of the lobby is still "available". Once the first request is complete and the database gets updated (lobby status gets set to "canceled"), other requests to cancel fail. So if successful, the lobby creator can get his points back 2 or more times.

This problem can also occur when 2 users join a lobby at the same time, since I handle that very similarly.

How can I make is so that the first request runs completely and wait for the database to update before other requests are handled.

Client

```
$('#cancelLobby').click( () =>{   
    socket.emit('cancelLobby', lobby-id);
});
```

Server

```
socket.on('cancelLobby', (id) => {
if(id){
    Coinflip.findById({_id: id}).lean().exec( (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if(res == null || res.status == "Completed" || res.status == "Canceled"){
            socket.emit('serverMessage', {
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'This lobby doesn\'t exist or has already ended'
            });
            return;
        }

        if(res.creator_name != socket.request.user.name){                       
            socket.emit('serverMessage', {
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'Error occured while canceling the lobby'
            });
        }else {
            Coinflip.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {status: 'Canceled'}}, (err) =>{
                if (err) throw err;

                socket.emit('serverMessage', {
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Lobby canceled successfully, you will get your points back shortly.'
                });
            });
        }
    })
}else{
    socket.emit('serverMessage', {
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        message: 'Error occured while canceling the lobby'
    }); 
}
});
```

Comment: Just keep a map of "currently-cancelling-ids"; set `mymap[id] = 1` before `findById`, `delete mymap[id]` after `findOneAndUpdate`, and change `if(id)` to `if (id && !mymap[id])`

Comment: @samhain1138 Works like a charm, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can process the event only once (both on the client and on the server):

```
$('#cancelLobby').one('click', () => {   
    socket.emit('cancelLobby', lobby-id);
});
```

or

```
socket.once('cancelLobby', (id) => {
...
});
```